# Drupal 7 - query using BETWEEN not working

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a query in Drupal 7 that is searching a custom table:

```
$query5 = "SELECT COUNT(reservation_id) as rcount5, reservation_id FROM {reservations} WHERE resource_id = :resource_id AND reservation_date = :reservation_date AND start_time BETWEEN :start_time AND :end_time";
$result5 = db_query($query5, array(':resource_id' => $resource_id, ':reservation_date' => $reservation_date, ':start_time' => $start_time, ':end_time' => $end_time));
```

The query is not working because I believe that it is not recognizing the BETWEEN function properly and returning the end_time because it exists.  Is there a way to show drupal or the db api that this is a BETWEEN statement?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it.  I tried both Clive's and Krister Andersson's solutions with the same result as my code.  The value for $start_time being used is 0600 stored as a varchar in the database.  The row that is being returned as a match in it has these values -> start_time = 0700, end_time = 0950.  The 0600 clearly is not BETWEEN 0700 and 0950.  Can't figure it out.  humph!

Comment: start_time and end_time should be numbers, not strings

Comment: @MariusIlie: Why should they be numbers? It's perfectly valid to represent a time using a 4 character string, it's done all the time. Remember this is a custom table, not part of the field API.

Comment: sorry, my bad. you can use strings also. but you also need the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Drupal 7 database API and add a `BETWEEN` argument like this:

```
$query5 = db_select('reservations', 'r')
  ->fields('r', array('reservation_id'))
  ->condition('resource_id', $resource_id)
  ->condition('reservation_date', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN');

$query5->addExpression('COUNT(reservation_id)', 'rcount5');
$result5 = $query->execute();
```

It's far easier to read in my opinion :)

Take a look at [Dynamic queries](http://drupal.org/node/310075) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `>=` and `<=` instead:

```
   $query5 = "SELECT COUNT(reservation_id) as rcount5, reservation_id 
              FROM {reservations} 
              WHERE resource_id = :resource_id AND 
              reservation_date = :reservation_date AND 
              (start_time >= :start_time AND start_time <= :end_time)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, came up with the answer.  First, my original code works fine.  I had to change the data type to int in the database and it worked fine after that.  Thanks.

The good news is that all of the answers given worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely sure if this is by default or a bug in db_query / db_select.

Let's assume that you save your timestamp in DB with the following format
2014-12-15 09:38:04
or just
2014-12-15

Now lets assume you want to search all rows related to one single day.
If you throw a raw MySQL query using BETWEEN it will work perfectly.
Example:

```
select * from table 
where timestamp between "2014-12-15" and "214-12-15";
```

However, if you create the query using db_query or db_select, the statement below will not work:
Example:

```
$query->condition('timestamp', array("2014-12-15", "2014-12-15"), 'BETWEEN');
```

For some reason, it seems Drupal compares from 2014-12-15 0:0:0 to 2014-12-15 0:0:0.

If you create the condition with the following format, it will work

```
$query->condition(
 'timestamp', 
  array("2014-12-15", "2014-12-15" . ' 23:59:59'), 
 'BETWEEN'
);
```

Using real filters, the statement would be:

```
$query->condition(
  'timestamp', 
  array($stardate, $endate . ' 23:59:59'), 
  'BETWEEN'
);
```

I'm hoping i'm wrong about this Drupal issue. Because it's really lame.

Regards,
Sharif.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->condition('timestamp', array("2014-12-15", "2014-12-15"), 'BETWEEN')
```

doesn't work on drupal because it doesn't have a real filter. 
the solution given by @Sharif El Shobkshy is the working solution.

```
$query->condition(
  'timestamp', 
  array($stardate, $endate . ' 23:59:59'), 
  'BETWEEN'
);
```

note the $stardate and endate must be in the php `date(Y-m-l)` format. But if the date is stored as integer, change it to `date(Yml,$_Post['date'])` and change the real filter too.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `COUNT()` and other field selection in your query, you should also use `GROUP BY` clause